# Python - last hour of postfix log

Tags: python, bash

I am looking for an effective way of getting the past hour of the maillog log file created by postfix. I want to do that in python or in bash.

So far I have extracted the month and the day that is saved in the postfix log:

```
now_m = today.ctime().split()[1]
now_d = int(today.ctime().split()[2])
```

but am stuck over here and need some fresh ideas.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code example:

```
Apr  2 11:53:15 server01 postfix/bounce[9177]: 62A347FB99: sender non-delivery notification: 6F4B67FB97
Apr  2 11:53:15 server01 postfix/qmgr[8140]: 5E9B07FB95: removed
Apr  2 11:53:15 server01 postfix/qmgr[8140]: 62A347FB99: removed
Apr  2 11:53:15 server01 postfix/qmgr[8140]: 6F5837FB98: from=<>, size=4054, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr  2 11:53:15 server01 postfix/bounce[9182]: 652D67FB9D: sender non-delivery notification: 6F5837FB98
Apr  2 11:53:15 server01 postfix/qmgr[8140]: 652D67FB9D: removed
Apr  2 11:53:15 server01 postfix/qmgr[8140]: 6EE717FB92: from=<>, size=4926, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr  2 11:53:15 server01 postfix/qmgr[8140]: 6F4B67FB97: from=<>, size=3448, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr  2 11:53:15 server01 postfix/smtpd[9163]: disconnect from unknown[10.0.0.4]
```

and another example:

```
Aug 30 09:00:56 server01 postfix/qmgr[2321]: 1654A7FB86: removed
Aug 30 09:01:57 server01 postfix/smtpd[4320]: connect from unknown[10.0.0.0]
Aug 30 09:01:57 server01 postfix/smtpd[4320]: disconnect from unknown[10.0.0.0]
Aug 30 09:02:16 server01 postfix/smtpd[4320]: connect from unknown[10.0.0.0]
Aug 30 09:02:16 server01 postfix/smtpd[4320]: 21F077FB86: client=unknown[10.0.0.0]
```

Comment: If you don't need the exact last hour, you can just use `grep` for a day+hour -- something like `grep "Sep  4 10:" mail.log`.  If you need the exact hour, you could write a python script to generate a regex that covers the past hour (which could contain values on a different day or month)

Comment: You'd probably get more help if you included a sample of a log file. Also, unless you're doing this as an exercise, have you looked for existing tools? Like [Postfix Contribs](http://jimsun.linxnet.com/postfix_contrib.html) (you have to like a page that has a note to Lynx users).

Comment: the `.ctime()` calls in your code example suggest that you should start with the most straightforward *working* solution (`ctime()` is not the way to get month, day from a date in Python) -- if you don't know how; [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Once you have something that works; measure how fast it is and set a goal how fast you would like it to be -- [update your question with this info](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32401222/edit).

Comment: @ Jonathan Vanasco - what if the time is 10:10AM - I'd only get the last ten minutes grepping "10:" and not really fresh data when grepping 9. I liked the idea though, was really simple!

Comment: I have provided code example in the question's body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple:

```
NOW=`date +%s`; THEN=`expr $NOW - 3600`; until (("$THEN" > "$NOW")); do DATE=`date -d @\$THEN +'%b %e %k:%M:%S'`; grep -e "^$DATE" /var/log/maillog && sed -n -e "/^$DATE/,\$p" /var/log/maillog && break; THEN=`expr $THEN + 1`; done
```

In other words:

1) get current time $NOW

2) get time one hour ago $THEN

3) if there is a line beginning with $THEN, print the line and everything after it (and break the cycle)

4) increment $THEN by one second and repeat until $NOW (or until you find something)

It's not very efficient and not very fast but will probably serve you well.

Answer (score 0):

The basic track is to read each line, and parse it's timestamp into a `datetime.datetime` object. There are several options to do so, e.g using its `.fromtimestamp` (static) method. Or the more general parsers (see utile)

Then use `datetime.datetime.now()` and subtract `datetime.timedelta(mins=60)`; the result can be compared to the parsed timestamp.

It as simple as that!
No need to do any manual, work.

PS add an example of the log file/line next time. The we can give the concrete example code